# Flask and React Docker containers not communicating via Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two containers - one containing a react app, another a flask app.

I can build both using the below docker-compose file and their respective Dockerfiles, and am able to access each via the browser on the ports specified. However, my React app's API calls to Flask are not being retrieved (they work without Docker in the picture).

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    middleware:
        build: ./middleware
        command: python main.py run -h 0.0.0.0
        volumes:
          - ./middleware/:/usr/src/app/
        ports:
          - 5000:5000
        env_file:
          - ./middleware/.flaskenv
    frontend:
        build:
          context: ./frontend/app
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
          - './frontend/app:/usr/src/app'
          - 'usr/src/app/node_modules'
        ports:
          - '3001:3000'
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=development
        links:
          - middleware
```

**Dockerfile for flask app**

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.0-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/
```

**Dockerfile React app**

```
# base image
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
ADD package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@0.9.5 -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I also have the below in my React app in `package.json` which enables me to make API calls to the flask app (again, this works fine without Docker)

```
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
```

Finally, project structure (in case useful)

```
website
|
|--middleware (Flask app)
  - Dockerfile
  - api
|--frontend (React app)
  -Dockerfile
  -app
|
|-docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: change `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",` to `"proxy": "http://middleware:5000",`

Comment: Use docker service names(`middleware`, `frontend`) when you need to access one service from another inside a docker network. Avoid using `127.0.0.1` as it resolves to the container itself and not the docker host as you are assuming.

Comment: BOOM, thank you guys! that did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As LinPy and leopal in the comments pointed out `127.0.0.1` in `package.json` needed to be changed to reference the correct flask container.

```
"proxy": "http://middleware:5000",
```